# Is the default case in a switch statement optional?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm building a JavaScript parser and there seem to be some differing opinions.

ECMA-262 seems to suggest that it is not optional, but Wikipedia says it is.

**[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):**

> *SwitchStatement :* **`switch (`** *Expression* **`)`** *CaseBlock*
>
> *CaseBlock :* **`{`** *CaseClauses<sub>opt</sub>* **`}`**
>
> **`{`** *CaseClauses<sub>opt</sub> DefaultClause CaseClauses<sub>opt</sub>* **`}`**

**[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Switch_statement):**

> `case default:` is optional.

Does Wikipedia just mean that you can literally write `case default:` if you want?

**EDIT**

Just realised I was reading ECMA wrong.  The first case block option i.e. **`{`** *CaseClauses<sub>opt</sub>* **`}`** allows you to miss out the default block.  Case closed (if you'll pardon the pun).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *CaseBlock* can be *either* of the following:

- { CaseClauses<sub>opt</sub> }
- { CaseClauses<sub>opt</sub> DefaultClause CaseClauses<sub>opt</sub> }

That's sort of a clumsy way of saying that there can be at most one *DefaultClause*, and you can put it anywhere in the *CaseBlock*.

Comment: Thanks, I realised this just after posting.  Seems I wasted a lot of time on beautiful formatting for nothing!

Answer (score 0):

That simply means you don't have to write a default case

Answer (score 0):

It is optional in the ECMA standard. The `CaseBlock` represents either or.